# Get date and whitelisted keyword from each single-line log entry

Tags: php, regex, text-extraction

I need a help from returning a matches at once, from the below provided strings. I need a date (between brackets) and status (Registered/Reachable):

```
[Feb 28 13:22:37] VERBOSE[1111] chan_sip.c:     -- Registered SIP \'1001\' at 127.0.0.1:8080
[Feb 28 13:22:37] NOTICE[1111] chan_sip.c: Peer '1001' is now Reachable. (471ms / 2000ms)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  So your example text has two entries and you need both of them?  Can you explain a little bit more about what you mean by getting the status?

Comment: Where did your attempts fail specifically? (While you say you're learning them, most of these regex-please-help-me questions are coding requests, hence the inquiry if you at least tried yourself).
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
/^\[([^\]]+)\].*(Registered|Reachable)/
```

Group 1 and 3 have your date and status.