# Replace embedded @ symbol with sub-word following it

Tags: php, replace

I have a task which requires me to replace a pattern of characters terminated by a `@` symbol with the sub-word immediately following it. So, given `presymbol@postsymbol` for example, the replacement would produce `postsymbol`.

I am currently using this pattern `'/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/'` to do the replacement, but my testers gave me feedback that putting " in front of the @, causes the replacement to fail.

How can I fix this pattern to output properly. Something similar to `'/(^|\s)(@|"@)([a-z0-9_]+)/'` ?

Comment: Yes sorry.. for not mentioning using preg_replace

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
/(^|\s)(@|"@)([a-z0-9_]+)/
```

If you add a new [match group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), `$2` becomes `$3`.

What you ought to do is simply making `"` optional:

```
...."?@....
```

Or use a non-capturing match group:

```
....(?:@|"@)....
```

Or possibly put it as another alternative into the first group:

```
....(^|\s|")....
```

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Regex.. bookmarked that one :) went for this one `'/(^|\s)?@([a-z0-9_]+)(?)/'`