# PHP - ( Regex ) - Find Files that do not contain -num X num

Tags: php, regex

This is a general regex question,although I will apply it in PHP.

I am trying to find all files that DO NOT contain strings like `-123x456` or `-12345x678` meaning that the format is always `-INT`x`INT`. (like image resolution) .

This string is a part of the filename. and the "constsnts" are the minus ( - ) sign before the string and the X in the middle ( which can be both capital letters or not )

With the help of [THIS](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) have come up with the expression:

```
^(?:(?!STRING).)*$
```

or in my case :

```
^(?:(?!x).)*$
```

But that will exclude all filenames that contain an `x`

How can I add the Numbers on both sides of the `x` when not knowing how many digits they are , but knowing that there COULD be a number before or after that is a part of the filename

(e.g. `myfile-x1-456x78`9 VR. `myfile-x12` )

I need a separate solution for `x` in specific , or for `X | x`  ...

Comment: You don't the negative assertion if you were to use `preg_grep()` with `PREG_GREP_INVERT` on a filename list. Also are you just asking for `\d+x\d+`?

Comment: Thank you mario for your input , but I am not sure what `\d+x\d+` means (no regex expert here ... )

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inverted search (on linux with the `grep` tool and `-v` or `--invert-match` argument) or as @mario suggested with [preg_grep()](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-grep.php) in PHP.

To answer your question use this RegEx: `^(?!.*?-\d+[xX]\d+)(.*)$` [explained demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD6wF6)

To match both `x` and `X` you can also use `(x|X)` or just `x` if used with the case insensitive regex modifier **i**.

Comment: Thanks ! it works .. also a big +1 for using that website .. the feature where it is automatically explains the regex is great !

Comment: as for your edit - this is another confusion I always have , which is the difference between `Xx` and `x|X` . but i guess that is for another question ... thanks again ..

Comment: `[]` denotes a character set, will match one character listed there so I listed both x and X. `|` is OR and will try to match the first one, if it fails it will try to match the second

Answer (score 0):

Why even use PHP on this at all?  Use grep's `-L` option to find files that don't match the regex.

```
grep -L -- '-\d+x\d+' *
```

You have to put the regex after a `--` so that grep does not think that the regex is a command line option.

Comment: Thanks for the info . I am on win machine , but I will give a try when I will get a chance to switch to linux . I will be using php because it is a part of a website ( ? )