# regular expression of string

Tags: php, regex

Using the following code that I already have:

```
$var =  "City 0.428371 2 BEIJING Beijing 39.91388888888889 116.39166666666667  Organization 0.392154 1 PBOC PBOC Motorsports Club  Company 0.38134 1";
```

Need to extract this:

> City 0.428371 2 BEIJING

Comment: What have *you* tried so far? -- (SO isn't a code writing service).
 See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: I have made this \bCi(\w*)y\b [0-9.]+ [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+ bt I got error

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

What did you try?

This would seem to do the trick:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $var, 5);
array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$extracted = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $var), 0, 4));
```

Bejing has to be one word, wouldn't work with "New York" for example.