# Basic regex placeholder for Javascript number

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am using `file_get_contents` to scrape some data from a web page.
This part is working fine. I just need 1 value on the page.
My regex is not great so it will be helpful if you can help.

This is the data I want to retrieve

```
var number = 100;
```

I only need to get the number. The number is always going to be different but `var number` will always be the same.

```
 $regex = '/var number =/';
 preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
```

The above will return `var number =`, how can I make it return the actual number?

Comment: Use a placeholder, like `(.*)` or `\d`...
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: @mario: (+1) for open source RegexBuddy alternatives, I didn't know it existed

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: `var\s+number\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*;`.

**What does this mean ?**

- `var` : match `var`
- `\s+` : match white space 1 or more times
- `number` : match `number`
- `\s*` : match white space 0 or more times
- `=` : match `=`
- `\s*` : match white space 0 or more times
- `(\d+)` : group and match a digit 1 or more times
- `\s*` : match white space 0 or more times
- `;` : match `;`

If you want to match several of these variables you should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg-match-all).

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rF9rW5)