# preg_replace doesn't match with two spaces between words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i need to format uppercase words to bold but it doesn't work if the word contains two spaces

is there any way to make regex match only with words which end with colon?

```
$str = "BAKA NO TEST: hey";    
$str = preg_replace('~[A-Z]{4,}\s[A-Z]\s{2,}(?:\s[A-Z]{4,})?:?~', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

output: `<b>BAKA NO TEST:</b> hey`

but it returns `<b>BAKA</b> NO TEST: hey`

the original `$str` is a multiline text so there are many lowercase and uppercase words but i need to change only some

Comment: Your last five questions seem to iteratively refine the same topic. Is the current regex the result of your own attempts or from somewhere else?
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: i got this regex from another topic but i've tried to change for what i need but it doesn't work that's why i'm asking for help.. i'm not good with regex...i'm getting new issues based on the first question

Comment: What about `$str = preg_replace('/[A-Z\s]+:/', '<b>$0</b>', $str);`?

Comment: look at your second `[A-Z]` clause and try to figure out how a single char class could possibly match `NO`.

Comment: i got the same output for both regex above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~[A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)*:~', '<b>$0</b>', $txt);
```

Explanations:

```
[A-Z]+      # uppercase letter one or more times
(?:         # open a non capturing group
    \s      # a white character (space, tab, newline,...)
    [A-Z]+  #
)*          # close the group and repeat it zero or more times
```

If you want a more tolerant pattern you can replace `\s` by `\s+` to allow more than one space between each words.

Comment: it didn't work even with a single space.. for example: `$str = "BAKA TEST" it formats only the first word`

Comment: @EddieD.: I don't know where you test your patterns, but it works fine.

Comment: i test in my real code.. well.. based on ur example i've changed mine and it worked.. like this `$str = preg_replace('~[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*:~', '<b>$0</b>', $str['descricao']);`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some good reason to use that regexp, try something simpler, like:

```
/([A-Z\s]+):/
```

Also, just so you know, you can use asterisk to specify *none or more* space characters: `\s*`