# preg_match won't collect work correctly

Tags: php, preg-match

It seems to be working correctly, but if you put leading characters it doesn't check that and if you put ending characters it doesn't check that.

I want to make sure a string is in this format:

```
6 Numbers | Hyphen | 1 Number | A-Z any case | Hyphen | 5 Numbers
```

So like this `123456-1a-12345` and `123456-1A-12345` should work.

```
$string = 'this12345-1A-12345'; // This works, and it shouldn't
$string = '12345-1A-12345this'; // This also works and it shouldn't

$pattern = "([0-9]{6}[-]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[-]{1}[0-9]{5})";
echo preg_match($pattern, $string);
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry I am really new to `preg_match`, and I can't find any good libraries on syntax.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must only add anchors to mark the start and end of the pattern (and add pattern delimiters):

```
$pattern = "~^([0-9]{6}[-]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[-]{1}[0-9]{5})$~";
```

As an aside, your pattern can be shorten to:

```
$pattern = '~^[0-9]{6}-[0-9][A-Z]-[0-9]{5}$~i';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: What does the `~` do and what does `~i` do? Can you explain that?

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I know, parenthesis can be used as delimiters but however it is the worst choice since it is very ambiguous in a regex pattern.

Comment: So if `~` are the new delimiters, then what is the `i` for?

Comment: @Arian: the `~` are used as pattern delimiters, the "i" is here for a case insensitive pattern. (you don't need to add lower case letters in your classes)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for explaining it to me! I'll remember not to use `(` & `)` as delimiters!

Comment: @Arian: the best delimiters you can use are characters you are sure to not write in your pattern. It is not always possible, but when I see people using `/` as delimiters to treat XML like ...

Comment: @Arian: check deceze link, you will see that you can use several type of delimiters.

Comment: @Arian: parenthesis are special characters in a pattern, they are used to define capturing groups.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ahhh okay, that makes sense! So don't use delimiters that can be used inside a pattern. Thanks again.

Comment: @Arian: exact <°))))))))>

Answer (score 3):

You can use `^` to make the regex check for beginning of line and `$` for the end of it.

```
$pattern = "(^[0-9]{6}[-]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[-]{1}[0-9]{5}$)";
```

This pattern will only apply if the string has nothing before and after your specifications.

Comment: `()` *are* delimiters.

Comment: I did not know that, thought they would only be used for defining groups - thanks!