# How regex works

Tags: php

I'm trying 'port' a register page from php into c# and I'm currently facing this issue:

```
if(ereg("^[0-9a-zA-Z]{12,12}$",$_GET["password"])) $code = ''; {

}

if(ereg("^[0-9a-zA-Z]{13,13}$",$_GET["password"])) $code = ''; {

}

if(ereg("^[0-9a-zA-Z]{14,14}$",$_GET["password"])) $code = ''; {

}
```

I can't understand what does it checks in the regex and what's with the character in the variable $code ( I mean , what kind of character it is so I can add the same character in c#)

Comment: You could actually paste the formatted code here, than pasting images.

Comment: the regex is checking if it is an alphanumeric string of a certain length

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: in reference to the comment by @user876345 : the regex syntax looks to be compatible with preg_match

Comment: If I paste the code instead of the image the character in the $code is shown like this $code = ''  , I don't know what's with that character added in the variable ..

Comment: @Jonnie `FF` is the control character for [form feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) and `SO` is the [shift out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters) control character.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` at the start of a RegEx means that the regular expression HAS to start with whatever comes next.

Everything between `[` and `]` are you you are matching. In your case, the number `0` to `9`, and the letter `a` through `z`, both capital and lower case.

The numbers inside `{}` means minimum and maximum length. So your first one has the be exactly 12 characters long.

The `$` at the end means that is the end of the line.

All in all, each RegEx means that it can ONLY have alpha-numeric characters, and the length is different for each.